# How can we match Haskell tuples to an Agda datatype?

Tags: haskell, tuples, ffi, agda

I would like to use Haskell code in Agda, for example, something like a function that gives back a list of pairs of integers and strings.

I saw this documentation:
https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.1.1/language/foreign-function-interface.html

But I don't know how to map Haskell tuples to an Agda type, because for example in a mapping like

```
{-# COMPILE GHC APair = data ?????? #-}
```

I don't know how to fill the ????-s, as I don't have the definition of the tuple data type.

However, pairs are not listed at the builtin pairings either.

How should I proceed?

Comment: Have a look at the standard library's [Foreign.Haskell](http://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Foreign.Haskell.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard library does this in `Foreign.Haskell.Pair` (https://agda.github.io/agda-stdlib/Foreign.Haskell.Pair.html). The relevant code is

```
record Pair (A : Set a) (B : Set b) : Set (a ⊔ b) where
  constructor _,_
  field  fst : A
         snd : B
open Pair public

{-# FOREIGN GHC type AgdaPair l1 l2 a b = (a , b) #-}
{-# COMPILE GHC Pair = data MAlonzo.Code.Foreign.Haskell.Pair.AgdaPair ((,)) #-}
```

There's a little bit of fiddling to account for the universe levels in the Agda type, which don't appear in the Haskell pairs. If you don't need that, this should suffice:

```
data Pair (A B : Set) : Set where
  _,_ : A → B → Pair A B

{-# COMPILE GHC Pair = data (,) ((,)) #-}
```